# How to get from region code to its timezone with C#/.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I've been puzzling around with RegionInfo and CultureInfo, but I still haven't managed to get a timezone with to determine the UTC offset.

I've got codes like NL for Netherlands and US-TX for the state of Texas, USA.

How can I get the UTC offset given an ISO 3166 or [ISO 3166-2](https://nl.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-2) code?

Comment: Have you considered using [Noda Time](http://nodatime.org/) ? Also note that the offset changes depending on daylight savings time.

Comment: The region codes are insufficient - Russia has multiple timezones but only one region code. Country codes have no correspondence to timezone names and timezones do change. Use Noda Time or any other library that uses IANA's Timezone database. Windows or .NET don't have that information

Comment: Looks like this problem is way bigger than I anticipated. India might have the same problem...